# Reinforcement learning based on change in discounted reward?

Tags: references, reinforcement-learning

In RL systems that I know about, such as Q-learning or A3C, the agent makes a determination of discounted future reward as a function of the current observations or current internal state, and the action it takes.

Are there RL algorithms where what we calculate from the current observations or current action is an expected *change* in discounted future reward?

For example, we might have an agent where every time the agent sees a blue light, its expected future discounted reward goes up by 1 unit. Perhaps a blue light signifies a certain reward after a delay, independently of any other rewards the agent might also have coming. The agent's observation on that time step is only the blue light, and its only "memory" is the amount of discounted reward it had been expecting on the previous time step.

Comment: Interesting question, even though it isn't very clear without maths. My guess is that if one could express the expected change within  [Belmann Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation), it should be possible.

Comment: If you formulate your environment as an MDP, you will need to add a *state*, which would necessarily include the current observation, all relevant memories, and some prediction of when the delayed rewards were expected. Whilst I could answer the question based on that assumption, it basically removes the premise of your question, Do you have an environment or problem you can describe that is closer to what you think you need this alterative RL for? I suspect that too will resolve to demonstrating how to represent what you want using usual MDP structure and normal RL, but it is not 100% clear

Comment: @NeilSlater Perhaps we could formulate the predicted reward A(t) = A(t-1)/beta + S(O(t)) - R(t), where beta<1 is the discount factor, O(t) is the observation on step t, R(t) is the reward on step t, S(O(t)) is the change in expected reward calculated from the observation. Then we can differentiate the error, (R(t) + beta * A(t+1) - A(t))^2, w.r.t. the parameters of S(). I haven't gotten this to work.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your suggestion. IMO, you should try first to use a normal MDP view of your problem, then explain why you think it doesn't fit. I think that will *probably* expose a misunderstanding on your part how to represent your problem in RL, and you will be able to use normal RL. However, it might also explain to someone trying to answer what is special about your case, and whether your idea about predicting changes in reward can be used somehow.